# Running python -m http.server does not load localhost

Tags: http, localhost, http.server

Previously when I ran the `python -m http.server` command from a folder it would show the link as something like "http://localhost:5500", but after I accidentally installed `npm install http-server` it no longer correctly shows localhost and instead shows something like this

`Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...`

Is there any way to fix this back to localhost? The `http://[::]:8000/` does not work and I get the error "This site can’t be reached"